# Bilding 3x3 array from cells vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have got a row with 9 cells, such as

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

I want to build a 3x3 matrix such as, for later do some operation with it

> 1,2,3
>
> 4,5,6
>
> 7,8,9

I have tried the following code

```
dim varr as variant
for i = 0 to 1
    for j = 1 to 3
        varr(i, j-1) = activesheet.cells(1, 3+i+j))
    next j
next i
```

which does not work (type mismatch), it is clear that I am not properly defining the array but i cannot figure it out.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should always explicitly declare your variables to avoid confusion and lots of errors. `Option Explicit` at the top of your module will force you to do that.

Then your array is not properly declared, as you mentioned. Then there was also something wrong with your logic for selecting the value from `ActiveSheet.Cells`. I think you need something like the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim varr(2, 2) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 0 To 2
        For j = 0 To 2
            varr(i, j) = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1 + j + (i * 3))
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 2
        For j = 0 To 2
            Debug.Print "varr(" & i & ", " & j & ") = " & varr(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: how can i see what is putting in the array? I have added debug.print, but it is returning a list in the immediate window.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you put `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1 + j + (i * 3))` before the `varr(i, j) = ActiveSheet...` line, it will print out the value that is currently being added to the array.

Comment: Add `Debug.Print "i=" & i & ", j=" & j` to see what i and j are.

Comment: I meant I would like to see the final array 3x3 layout, if it is possible.

Comment: Sure, that's what the above printouts do. Otherwise you would have to go through new for loops at the end. I will update my answer.